# HTML table maintain column width on print

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Roll No</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th>Address</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>Ankush</td>
     <td>15</td>
     <td>10th</td>
     <td>105</td>
     <td style="width:10%">1234567890</td>
     <td style="width:20%">xyzdegdgrebrhbrgh</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Table is losing custom column widths at print time. It is working ok on normal page but columns width style is lost at printing time.

Comment: Did you try to put the table style in a @media print css?

Comment: try adding table layout fixed and word break break-all in your print css

Answer (score 0):

While printing Web page, the margins are set by browser settings. If your browser settings are okay, then you should use a media query targeted to 'print'.And if you want to print as shown in browser, you need to main page height and width in absolute unit, like inch.